# Slice in python - is it a copy or just a pointer?

Tags: python, list, slice

```
>>> a = [3, 2]
>>> a[0:1][0] = 1
>>> a
[3, 2]

>>> a[0:1] = [1]
>>> a
[1, 2]
```

What does `a[0:1]` mean?

1. If it's a pointer to the range of `a`, then `a[0:1][0] = 1` should change the value of `a`.
2. If it's a copy of the range of `a`, then `a[0:1] = [1]` shouldn't change the value of `a`.

I think the result of the two is inconsistent with each other. Could you please help me work out the problem?

Comment: I saw the documentation looks like `a[0:1][0] = 1`  calls .`__setitem__` and `a[0:1] = [1]` calls `__setslice__` so behavior are different

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan No. `__setitem__` is nowadays used and replaces `__setslice__`. The big difference here is `__get*__` vs. `__set*__`.

Comment: @glglgl yes I was reading doc for 2.7 it clearly says: "This method is deprecated. If no `__setslice__()` is found, or for extended slicing of the form `self[i:j:k]`, a slice object is created, and passed to `__setitem__()`, instead of `__setslice__()` being called." So ultimately it is `__setitem__()` that is used differently in both syntax.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan The same essentially holds for `__getslice__` vs. `__getitem__`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Internally, this is a big difference:

```
>>> a = [3, 2]
>>> a[0:1][0] = 1
```

is a shorthand for

```
temp = a[0:1]
temp[0] = 1
```

and is internally expressed as

```
a.__getitem__(slice(0, 1)).__setitem__(0, 1)
```

resp.

```
temp = a.__getitem__(slice(0, 1))
temp.__setitem__(0, 1)
```

so it accesses a part of the list, making a separate object, and doing an assignment on this object, which is then dropped.

On the other hand,

```
>>> a[0:1] = [1]
```

does

```
a.__setitem__(slice(0, 1), [1])
```

which just operates on the original object.

So, while looking similar, these expressions are distinct on what they mean.

Let's test that:

```
class Itemtest(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name
    def __setitem__(self, item, value):
        print "__setitem__", self, item, value
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        print "__getitem__", self, item
        return Itemtest("inner")

a = Itemtest("outer")
a[0:1] = [4]
temp = a[0:1]
temp[0] = 4
a[0:1][0] = 4
```

outputs

```
__setitem__ outer slice(0, 1, None) [4]
__getitem__ outer slice(0, 1, None)
__setitem__ inner 0 4
__getitem__ outer slice(0, 1, None)
__setitem__ inner 0 4
```

Answer (score 9):

Slicing a list creates a **shallow copy**- it is not a reference to the original. So when you get that slice, it is not bound to the original `list` `a`. Therefore, you can try and change a single element of it, but it is not stored in a variable so no changes will be made to any original `list`.

To clarify, with the former to you doing `__getitem__`- accessing part of the list (a copy):

```
a[0:1][0] = 1
```

You are editing the slice `[0:1]`, which is a only shallow copy of `a`, so will not edit `a` itself.

But with the latter, one is calling `__setitem__`, which will of course edit the object in-place.:

```
a[0:1] = [1]
```

You are directly referring to and editing part of `a`, so it changes in real-time.

Answer (score -1):

The following statement:

```
>>> a[0:1] = [1]
```

assigns the list `[1]` as a subset of the list `a` from `0` to `1`.

By doing `a[0:1][0]` you are getting the first element of `[3]` which is 3. Then if you try to assign it a value of 1, it simply wont work because 3 cannot be 1. However, if you stick to `a[0:1]`, you are getting `[3]`, which **can** be changed to `[1]`. Hope that helps

#### Examples

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> a[1:4]
[2,3,4]

>>> a[1:4] = [6,5,4,3,2]
>>> a
[1,6,5,4,3,2]
```

Comment: It looks OP understand this, He is looking why two assignment statement's behaviors are  different.

Comment: @cstur4, I have added explanation before the Examples heading. Please read. Thank you

Comment: @sshashank124 at least one of your examples is incorrect. `b[0] = 2` **will** change the first element of `b` from `1` to `2`.

Comment: *"it simply wont work because 3 cannot be 1"* -- That's not what that means. `x[key] = value` means `x.__setitem__(key, value)`. See docs: [`object.__setitem__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setitem__)